# 3D Sound - no rolloff?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm trying to use the rolloff effect in 3D sound, but am having trouble. I have a near sensor which is triggering properly, but no matter where the character stands in my scene, there is no rolloff to the sound -- it's either on or off. Here's the settings. I can't find any decent documentation on this, and the properties don't seem particularly intuitive.

These are my settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A more detailed documentation on the 3D sound options you find in the [Wiki on Sound Actuator](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aAnOrdinaryKitten/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Actuators/Sound/) it illustrates the meaning of the cone and all the options.

A older [post](http://bgetutorials.wordpress.com/2007/11/28/3d-sound-in-blender/) mentions that 3D sound only works with mono (WAV) files. if this still applies you could convert your sound with a tool like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

I edited the file from the post mentioned above and needed to adjust some values in order to hear anything and uploaded it [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/29371).